# question about unitary matrix and PSD matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, unitary-matrices

B,C are two tall matrices but are not assumed to have full column rank. Show that $BB^H=CC^H$ if and only if $C=BQ$ for some unitary matrix Q with k x k dimension.

I try to use EVD on both $CC^H$ and $BB^H$. it seems like that Q is a matrix whose columns are the eigenvectors of $CC^H$. However, I cannot find the exact Q matrix.

some thoughts：
if B, C is assumed to have full column rank, then $CC^H$ is invertible. Then I can find $Q = C(C^{H}C)^{-1}$ so that C=BQ and Q can be confirmed to be unitary.
but it does not follow the requirements of the question.

Any hints or comments? thanks

Comment: What is a *tall* matrix and what does $A^H$ denote, is it the hermitian conjugate?

Comment: tall matrix means the matrix A $\in C^{m \times n} $ where m > n, $A^H$ denotes the hermitian conjugate. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: the wording is awkward here.  It really should say "iff $C$ may be written as $C=BQ$ for unitary $Q$", since we can also find $C=BA$ for non-unitary $A$ when $B$ has linearly dependent columns (obvious example is when $B, C =\mathbf 0$). I suggest doing a  SVD on $B$ and $C$.

Comment: Let $BB^H=AA^H$ for some matrix $A$ of full column rank. Then one may prove that $B=AU^H$ and $C=AV^H$ for some matrices $U$ and $V$, each with orthonormal columns. Since $U$ and $V$ have the same size, there is an isometry $Q$ such that $V^HQ=U^H$. Hence $B=CQ$.

Comment: but $BB^H$ is not full column rank,  it can not equals a matrix with full rank, right?